# Trouble Reloading UITableView

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create an iphone application that reads a json feed and I am having some trouble updating a TableView.

This is my TableViewController header file:

```
@interface LiveNewsController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

NSMutableData *responseData;
NSMutableArray *articleArray;

UITableView *tblView;

}

-(void) refreshPressed: (id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;

@end
```

These are ***some*** parts of my TableViewController implementation file:

```
@implementation LiveNewsController

@synthesize tblView;

-(id) init {
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        self.title = @"Live News";
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"I am here %d",[articleArray count]);
    return [articleArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath called. Data size %d", [articleArray count]);


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [articleArray objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}

-(void) refreshPressed: (id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Reload Pressed. Data size: %d", [articleArray count]);
    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my .xib file with the connections:
[image: IB Screenshot]

So the main idea is the following:

1. Fetch articleArray
2. When refresh is pressed update view (the data is being fetched correctly but the snippet doesn't show it here)

numberOfRowsInSection and CellForRowAtIndexPath are only being called once when the view loads but nothing happens when I press the reload button.

I checked tblView and it is ***nil***. I did some research and read that this is usually caused by some erroneous connections in the .xib file but I have triple checked that and I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the `UITableView` *tblView*, the `UITableViewController`  has already one (and therefore all subclasses too).
Just try `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

Comment: I tried removing the tblView, nothing changed. The app still works as it did but my initial problem is still there. The data is not updating.

Comment: IT WORKED ! You were correct there was a small latency in the internet connection though. Thank you !